# Accessing OS X Per-User Screen Sharing from a Windows PC

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm not sure if Stack Overflow is the right place for this question, but I am trying to find a way to set up additional developers with access to our one iMac so they can use XCode. So in a roundabout way this is a programming question.

I discovered that OS X supports [per-user screen sharing](http://www.macstories.net/reviews/os-x-lion-screen-sharing-overview/) which allows additional users to remote into the Mac, login, and use it, without interrupting any other users of the system, including someone who's physically using it. This sounds good for us since we only have one Mac. However it sounds like the remote client *also* needs to be a Mac. Does anyone have experience with this per-user screen sharing? And is it possible to access it from Windows 7? Basically we're trying to save on purchasing additional Macs if possible.

If the per-user screen sharing can't handle it, perhaps there's a way to run a VNC server on OS X that supports multiple sessions?

Comment: Got it working. I used [TightVNC Java Viewer 2.1](http://tightvnc.com/) and it allows you to connect from any OS to an OS X screen sharing session. Per-user works fine, I am able to work on the Mac from my Windows system while someone else is physically using the Mac as well. The only thing is in the screen-sharing options on the Mac a VNC password needs to be set.

Comment: Apparently the trick is that you do not want to check "Allow anyone to connect"

Comment: @TJMott so where would you enter a username for a particular user you want to connect with in TightVNC Java Viewer?